# Can I write my Jenkins pipelines as Yaml instead of groovy?

Tags: jenkins

I want to write and configure my Jenkins pipelines using code like I would do in tools like concourse or Drone. The idea is not to leave it into UI driven configurations which I have to do even if I use groovy for a lot of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a Jenkins library, [wolox-ci](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/04/25/configuring-jenkins-pipeline-with-yaml-file/) will handle what you are looking for. You will still need a Jenkinsfile, but it will be reduced to this:

```
@Library('wolox-ci') _

node {

  checkout scm

  woloxCi('.woloxci/config.yml');
}
```